# django-nonrel: add element in LisftField of ForeignKeys

Tags: django, mongodb, foreign-keys, django-nonrel, listfield

I'm trying to implement a list of foreignKeys in django-nonrel (I'm using mongo as db).

### Here is the code:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
from django_mongodb_engine.contrib import MongoDBManager
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField

class FriendList(models.Model):
    objects = MongoDBManager()
    list = ListField(models.ForeignKey('AWUser'))

    def add_friend(self, awuser):
        # awuser must be an instance of AWUser - I removed tests for more clarity
        self.list.append(awuser)
        self.save()

class AWUser(models.Model):
    objects = CustomUserManager()
    user = EmbeddedModelField('User')
    friends = EmbeddedModelField('FriendList')
```

The problem is that when I call *user.friends.add_friend(user1)*, I have the error *"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'"*.

### Breaking example (made using ./manage shell console):

```
$>user = AWUser.objects.all()[0]
$>user1 = AWUser.objects.all()[1]
$>user.friends.add_friend(user1)
#ask me if you need the complete error - I don't put it more more clarity
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute '_meta'
```

What I basically need is to create friend lists.
Please feel free to recommend a different implementation if you think mine is not good. :) I would love to have my implementation working though...
Also, I did not put all the variables of AWUser for more clarity but I can add them if necessary.

### Related project dependencies:

- django 1.3.1   (installed as django-nonrel)
- django-mongodb-engine 0.4.0
- djangotoolbox==0.9.2
- List item
- pymongo==2.1.1

Thanks for your help.

### UPDATE:

I tried to change the code as said in the post "[ListField with ForeignField in django-nonrel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14101834/listfield-with-foreignfield-in-django-nonrel?rq=1)" but I still have the same error...

Answer (score 1):

According to the Django MongoDB Engine documentation, it suggests to use EmbeddedModel from djangotoolbox:

```
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField, EmbeddedModelField

class Post(models.Model):
    ...
    comments = ListField(EmbeddedModelField('Comment'))

class Comment(models.Model):
    text = models.TextField()
```

Edit:  Forgot the link: http://django-mongodb-engine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/embedded-models.html

Answer (score 0):

I actually just figured out what was wrong.
It is apparently impossible to declare the foreign key class type as a string when in a Listfield. Weird...
If it happens to you, just do the following change:

```
list = ListField(models.ForeignKey('AWUser'))
```

becomes:

```
list = ListField(models.ForeignKey(AWUser))
```

If anyone as a good explanation of what is going on, I'd love to hear it :)